# How to combine two windows as one in Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

In Terminal I can use `Command + T` to create Tabs in one Window, check below:

[image]

but now, I opened two windows like this, how to merge them as one liker upper:

[image]

I have tried drag one into another, but not work.

my macos Version is: Catalina 10.15.7 (19H524)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to be able to drag one into another, you have to turn the Tab Bar on from the View menu, or use ⇧⌘T, and then drag the tabs.  Both the source and the destination need to have the Tab Bar turned on.

Or, from the Window menu... `Merge All Windows`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way in Terminal Menu bar:

```
Window -> Merge Window -> Merge All Windows
```